# Forcing custom item renders to refresh

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an AdvancedDataGrid. One of the columns in the grid displayed with help of custom render. During the application run, I set another custom render to the same column. When I scroll data in the grid (change values for the custom renders) they display new view correctly.

I want that they dispaly new view automatically (when I set them): so I think I have to call them and tell tham to refresh rgeir views. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [invalidateList()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/AdvancedListBase.html#invalidateList%28%29)

Comment: I found the problem. I used to set ItemRender via rendererProviders, but when I set it directly on the column - everything works fine! Thank you!

Comment: I can theorize.  If rendererProviders is an array, changing on element inside that array will not trigger data binding and will therefore not update the column in question.  Without reviewing the source code  can't say for sure, though.